# List of tweets si allways null

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to get a list of tweets  but the result tweets list must be final,and this is a problem because  I want to returnt de result with the list.World be possible to return the result once is filled??

```
public class FollowingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TweetFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    //ListView homeList;
    //SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mviewPager;
    private List<Fragment> listaFragments;
    TwitterConnect twc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_following);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        twc = new TwitterConnect();
        Result<List<Tweet>> result = twc.getHomeTimeLine();//result is always null


        listaFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        listaFragments.add(TweetFragment.newInstance(1));
        listaFragments.add(TweetFragment.newInstance(2));
        listaFragments.add(TweetFragment.newInstance(3));


        // Creamos nuestro Adapter
        mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                listaFragments);

        // Instanciamos nuestro ViewPager
        mviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        // Establecemos el Adapter
        mviewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FollowingActivity.this, ComposeTweet.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

And this is the clas whre I have to get the list

```
public class TwitterConnect {
    TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient;
    StatusesService statusesService;
    Result<List<Tweet>> tweets;

    public TwitterConnect(){
        twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
    }

    private void callHomeTimeLine(){

        statusesService.homeTimeline(200, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
                setHomeTimeLine(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.e("FAILURE", "Fallo en callHomeTimeLine");
            }
        });

    }

    private void setHomeTimeLine( Result<List<Tweet>> result){
        this.tweets = result;
    }

    private Result<List<Tweet>> getTweets() {
        return this.tweets;
    }

    public Result<List<Tweet>> getHomeTimeLine(){
        callHomeTimeLine();

        return getTweets();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `success()` is asynchronous, so you have to wait until it is called to return the list of tweets.

You can do:

```
public void getHomeTimeLine(){
    statusesService.homeTimeline(200, null, null, null, null, null, null, new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
            displayTweets(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

        }
    });
}
```

Then you could display the tweets or do what you want in this method:

```
private void displayTweets(Result<List<Tweet>> tweets) {
    // Your logic
}
```

Comment: I have edited the first psost with the changes I have done

Comment: You did the same logic that you had, but in other way. Try doing what i posted